# How to call function from appended row and template literals

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, template-literals

I'm having problems with calling function.

I have made function that loops through array and appends customer info in each row.
I would like to have `onclick` to call another function and pass one parameter.

```
  aClanovi.forEach((oClan) => {
    $("#table_body").append(
      `<tr><td>${oClan.Ime}</td><td>${oClan.Prezime}</td><td>${oClan.Sport}</td><td>${oClan.Uloga}</td><td>${oClan.UlogaKraj}</td><td>${oClan.Clanarina}</td><td><a href='#editMemberModal' class='edit' data-bs-toggle='modal'><i class='material-icons' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Edit'>&#xE254;</i></a></td><td><a href='' id='ObrisiClana' onclick='obrisiClana(oClan.OIB)'><i class='material-icons' title='Obrisi'>&#xe872;</i></a></td></tr>`
    );
  });
```

```
const obrisiClana = (OIB) => {
  console.log(OIB);
};
```

Main problem is within this
`<a href='' id='ObrisiClana' onclick='obrisiClana(oClan.OIB)'><i class='material-icons' title='Obrisi'>&#xe872;</i></a>` and onclick.

All customer info's are showing, but I get error whenever I try to press delete button.

````
Error: 
Uncaught ReferenceError: obrisiClana is not defined
    onclick http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html?:1```
````

Comment: The `obrisiClana` function must be defined **globally**. Try `window.obrisiClana = (OIB) => { ... }`

Comment: With that adjustment I get new error - oClan is not defined.
If I use `obrisiClana(oClan.OIB)` outside of `append` It works fine. It returns in console log all OIB datas from array.

Comment: Are you sure the error isn't referring to `oClan.OIB`? You seem to have forgotten to insert that value into the template. `onclick='obrisiClana(oClan.OIB)'` should presumably be `onclick='obrisiClana(${oClan.OIB})'` instead.

Comment: Also, if you're putting the function name in the `onclick` attribute, it needs to be a global function. You can't define it inside an `$(function(){ ... })` block, unless you explicitly attach it to the `window` object: `window.obrisiClana = (OIB) => { ... };`

Comment: Function `const obrisiClana = (OIB) => {console.log(OIB)` is 'standing' on its own. It is global as far as I know. It is not part of any other function.
I have made a mistake with putting `${obrisiClana(oClan.OIB)}` instead of `obrisiClana(${oClan.OIB}` and It is working now only with `window.obrisiClana`. Still wont work with const obrisiClana..

Comment: Just **don't** attach event listeners through `onclick` attributes in html, even less for html that is dynamically constructed and appended.